# Wordpress or Drupal?

Tags: wordpress, drupal

I am planning to build a training site which will accommodate multiple users. It will also have lots of custom pages with videos in them. Which CMS/CMF is better suited for this project? Please advise..

Comment: currently your question can not have an objective answer. the reason is simple - the videos are supported on both so there is no objective way to discriminate. you already have a lot of good and detailed answers, but still none of them are objective (even the most objective of the answerers will show you the features that 'rock', comparatively). you'll have to decide and specify what is important to you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wordpress is designed from the ground up to be a blog, but also to be modular.  Drupal is designed to be a complete CMS out of the box, but there are also extensions for Drupal too.  Both are CMS systems, but again, Wordpress is really designed to be a blogging platform.  Also, Drupal is a little more complicated at first and has a higher learning curve.

However, you can do what you are trying to do with either one.  In addition to out of the box functionality, you can customize both Drupal or Wordpress.  People tend to specialize in one or the other, and the choice comes down to personal preference (people make a living off of being Drupal or Wordpress developers, that's what's great about open source!).  Once you become proficient in PHP and the CMS platform of choice, you can build your own extensions/modules and have a very custom website, but I would minimize customization to only what you absolutely need.  If you are creative in using the framework and freely available modules, you may not need to write any code.

Lastly, Drupal is getting a complete re-write with [version 7](http://drupal.org/node/725382), which people have been waiting a long time for!  If you want to get into Drupal, you may want to look into the newest version.

Edit: Personally, I prefer Wordpress, I think the admin section looks great, gives you a lot of control, but without being overwhelming (however, my opinion doesn't really matter).  I really think Wordpress has a lower learning curve.  I'm also pretty sure, although you haven't given many details, but if you are planning on having simple pages with videos on them, and want access to those pages to be restricted only to authenticated users, I'm pretty sure you can do that without any custom PHP coding, just some HTML.

Here's a couple helpful links for Wordpress:

- [Restrict Page View to Authenticated Users](http://www.wprecipes.com/how-to-restrict-page-view-to-authenticated-users)
- [Setting your Posts or Entire Blog to Private](http://wordpress.tv/2009/01/14/setting-your-posts-or-entire-blog-to-private/)

It can be confusing trying to decide which CMS to dive into; I hope that helps a little!

Comment: WordPress has been shifting over to function as a CMS for a long time now.

Comment: I agree, and for a long time you could use it as a CMS, especially with a little creativity.  However, it's still a blog by default after installation.  And it was only a few months ago that the admin controls had out of the box ability to point to a static page instead of the default "Posts" page: http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page

Comment: Thanks! As of now I am leaning towards Drupal. I am reading their docs like crazy. But yah it has a very high learning curve. In Wordpress I was basically a stranger to coding when I started using it yet I was able to build several websites already. However, that's also the main reason why I am not leaning towards it because it's too easy which leads me to think that it may not be very customizable when I do crucial changes in the future.

Comment: @Joann: With the advent of the new taxonomy system in WP, you couldn't be farther from correct.

Comment: Sounds like Kevin below would back up your sentiment.

Comment: I've been working with WordPress since about 2.1 and *believe* me - it is *insanely* customisable!

Comment: WP 3.0 isn't proven yet- Drupal 6 has been around since 2008 and has been doing it all that time. So these 'new' things like taxonomy and menus and content types, its been in Drupal for years. In my opinion as a developer Drupal is far more structured when you need to extend.

Comment: @Joann, do your matrix, that's the only thing that'll bring some peace of mind - for example as you say you might only have 2 weeks to get up to speed with internals or you have a bunch of wp css ready to use, etc... do your own score.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is **Drupal.**

I've been running various websites, and few years ago I decided to use Drupal as my main CMS engine and I never looked back.

I used Joomla, phpNuke, Mambo and WordPress before and nothing is as flexible, as maintainable as Drupal.

My biggest website – [www.mugen.pl](http://www.mugen.pl/) has **14853 registered users** so I can confirm Drupal is just perfect for big, heavily used web portals.

Drupal has few wonderful 'social-networking' modules I make an excellent use of to make sure my users are keen to stay on the website, sneak preview: (sorry, I've got only screenshots in Polish):

[image]
<sub>(source: [mugen.pl](http://www.mugen.pl/images/nowy-profil.png))</sub>

Unfortunately for Drupal, sometimes it takes a while to understand this system. Some theming stuff is not that obvious at first, but the [online community](https://www.drupal.org/forum) is huge and always helpful.

Additionally, Drupal has excellent support for SEO. It’s built-in “path” module allows to set custom URLs for every item on the page, and other available modules (i.e. Nodewords) allow to set custom meta data for every subpage.

When you decided to go with Drupal, you should have a look at the following modules:

- Content Construction Kit  - http://drupal.org/project/cck
- Views - http://drupal.org/project/views
- Custom breadcrumbs - http://drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs
- Last Node - http://drupal.org/project/last_node
- Nodewords - http://drupal.org/project/nodewords
- Fivestar - http://drupal.org/project/fivestar

Go with Drupal ;-)

Answer (score 3):

With the new release of WordPress 3.0, I would have to say WP. Many useful updates just came around the bend (menu system et al) that make it even easier to create a "site" out of a WP installation instead of just a "blog".

Drupal is **extremely** powerful and accommodating to the time-allowed developer, but falls short on the *ease-of-use*-side of things (at least from my experiences.

In short, if you're looking to make a site that's easy to install, update, and maintain - especially for posting media, go with WordPress.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Read both JohnB's and Lance May's answers. The choice is quite tricky so the only way you can make a good decision is to do your own feature comparison/score matrix.

List all the features that you need and assign importance score to them - then objectively go through both systems (or ask again on so) to get their scores.

This will also help you if you have to justify your decision later.

In the end both are good, both have quirks and both will get the job done.

Answer (score 2):

WordPress is just easy to understand, for both the developer and the content editors.

WordPress is best suited for sites with:

1) *Typical CMS needs* - Pages, Posts, Menus - I would also include embedded videos in this list

2) *Low to Moderate Traffic Loads* - I know there are sites like Smashing Magazine that user WordPress under high-load, but I am sure there is some custom code added to introduce a better caching architecture and multiple servers

3) *Hand off to Client for Content Editing* - In my opinion, the best feature of WP is the admin user interface. The sleek visual design, smart use of ajax controls, and the simple layout makes it possible to hand off content editing to "non-technical" people

When I start a WP site, I create a new theme with two files, index.php and styles.css. Then I build my own, custom theme, that is uniquely designed for my project. Examples of my work are http://perqworks.com, http://janemonheitonline.com and http://generalordersno9.com. As you can see, these are not blogs, but CMS sites. I agree, WP was a blog platform, but it has proven itself as a CMS-lite application.

Comment: Here's a article by Jeff A about using WP for high traffic sites: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/04/behold-wordpress-destroyer-of-cpus.html.  Basically, to optimize Wordpress, there's caching modules for your pages: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-cache/, optionally setup MySQL Query Cache: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html, and if you run it from your own web server, tweaking those settings as well.

Comment: Good references, I come from working with the Symfony framework were caching is core functionality. I understand the caching plugins provide a huge improvement, but it concerns me that caching is a plugin and not a core feature. My concern may be unfounded, but my spidey sense is cautioning me.

Comment: Bear in mind Jeff A's article is over 2 years old now, and WordPress has come a long way since then (including built-in caching).

Comment: I did not know WP had built in caching. I will have to do a little research. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer WordPress because of its extensibility and easy install and modifications.

Version 2.0 has introduced a bunch of features (like custom post types) that makes using it as a CMS easy.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress is mostly use for blogging and Drupal is used for creating websites. YOu should consider using drupal for that ;)

Answer (score 1):

You may be lured to WP immediately from how quick it is to get started. But in the long term, do yourself a favor and use Drupal. It's a proven CMS framework and less prone to security issues from contributed modules. I can count on two hands how many times a WP plugin has bit me in the ass, even highly rated ones. It has very granular security also, so you know exactly what your users can and cannot do.

I've used both and Drupal is just easier to extend and configure. I don't get why people think it has a huge learning curve.

Answer (score 1):

I also think a big deal breaker is the **end user experience** - WordPress makes it just so damn easy to manage your website, all whilst looking (in my opinion) rather beautiful at the same time.

Every client I've handed a WP site to has been impressed with it's simplicity - as the iPad put it;

> You already know how to use it!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer Drupal over Wordpress . Drupal is made for flexibility . But you must know how to do it , ie all . You may need some time to read how to do with that module x and how to with module Y . But once you have learned you will be comfortable to do any site.

The main advantage of Drupal is CCK and Views . Wordpress 3 have come with CCK , but Drupal has it from version 5. Now we are moving to 7, and it still misses Views :) . Yes ofcourse wordpress is a wonderful tool for blogging with ease. But when talking other than blog, you may want to opt for Drupal . Once you have learned how to do with drupal , you will never say wordpress .

If some one is against Drupal then he may have not used or learned it to the extent :) . So my suggestion for you to checkout Drupal 6 for now , as Drupal 7 is still in alpha for the present time.